# Accessing unknown setter method

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors, class-method

hey I am getting an error **accessing unknown class method 'setFirstName'** but I am trying to access the variable which are already synthesized here is the code.

Comment: is your property name is firstName ?

Comment: ok when i am trying to add the code ,this showing some error ,what should i do ,and reputation is also below 20 ,so thats why i am unable to add the entire xcode project.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says "unknown **class** method"! Are you calling the method to a `class` or an `instance`?

Comment: Its obvious, you never call an instance.

Comment: @Ali3n: um... what? You can have `MyClass.setFirstName("FOO")` when you mean to say `MyClass c = new MyClass(); c.setFirstName("FOO")`. That sounds like a great blind guess what's wrong to me, since we haven't seen any code.

Comment: i am trying to access the variables